# MSSQL Linux Crashes with data files on EXT4 formated ZVOL Reason: 0x00000003

Tags: sql-server, linux, crash

```
       Reason: 0x00000003
      Message: 0 == (m_PhysicalSectorSize % m_LogicalSectorSize)
   Stacktrace: 0000558d9d8c90c1 0000558d9d91ff08 0000558d9d8cd02c
               0000558d9d8d0965 0000558d9d8cdc3b 0000558d9d8cd4d2
               0000558d9d8ce20f 0000558d9d8c2c17 0000558d9d8c1e66
      Process: 300 - sqlservr
       Thread: 471 (application thread 0x1158)
  Instance Id: af6ea342-baec-44de-a791-9c7c9537116a
     Crash Id: 94efb159-ed5c-4247-b180-a5b3a4cceb29
  Build stamp: d250a9f0724e59ff452e464a4ab43d5d070a14aef28f4ce3a48a2d785986baa6
```

Wanted to make use of ZFS over your run-of-the-mill disk to get all the benefits it offers. However it's a [known issue that this isn't supported](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/13) in such that you can't simply place the data files on a mounted pool. So I tried to use ZFS's ZVOL option to give me a traditional partition backed by ZFS, copied the database files over (after shutting down the server), remounted the new partition in the same place as the old one, and attempted to start to get the error shown above.

I'm semi-sure it's because of mssql not supporting ZFS but I wanted to post this here if anyone has any input on what might be happening.

*At the moment I'm making due with a file block device located on the pool and dealing with the inherit chicken-egg problem whenever it happens.*